# Scanner, input username and password with 3 attempts

Tags: loops

How can I create a program with the following specification..

Using `Scanner`, ask the user to input the username and password with maximum of 3 attempts using a loop. If the username and password are both correct, the program will ask a secret question; if the answer to the question is correct, then it will display "welcome" and if the answer is wrong it will display "program terminated".

If the username and password are both wrong, it will give the user 3 attempts and if all attempts are wrong it will also display "program terminated".

Thank you...

im using netbeans ide..

so far my problems were..
it don't display terminated when all attempts are wrong. 
in 1st attempt, if both username and password are correct but the secret answer is wrong it doesn't give 2nd attempt..

```
  `Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    for (int x=0;x<3;x++){
        System.out.print("username: ");
        String username = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("password: ");
        String password = scan.nextLine();

        if (username.equals("admin")&&password.equals("secret")){
            System.out.print("sport? ");
            String sport = scan.nextLine();
            if (sport.equals("sepak")){
                System.out.println("welcome");
            }
            else 
                System.out.println("terminated");
            break;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Ummmm... Which language are you using?

Comment: Sounds like a homework/school assignment to me.  Please don't try to get other do your work for you.

Comment: Sounds like homework...please add the homework tag if it is. People are more likely to help if they know you're trying to get help and not just trying to get somebody to do your project for you.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like homework to me, and since you haven't provided any code, I'll assume you just need some guidance to get started.

Here's some pseudo code for you

1. Initialize `attempts` to 0
2. While `attempts` < 3

   1. `username` = read from scanner
   2. `password` = read from scanner
   3. If `username` equals `"correct username"` AND `password` equals `"correct password"`

      1. Print "welcome"
      2. Return from function
   4. Increment `attempts`
3. Print "program terminated"
4. Exit program

Answer (score 1):

You can start by writing out the steps in full detail. This is fairly self-evident, so I am not giving the answer away.

1. Ask username and password for the first time.
2. If both are correct, go to 7. If not, go to 3.
3. Ask username and password for the second time.
4. If both are correct, go to 7. If not, go to 5.
5. Ask username and password for the third time.
6. If both are correct, go to 7. If not, **terminate**.
7. Ask secret question.
8. If answer is correct, **welcome**. If not, **terminate**.

Then, you can think about how to use a loop and some bookkeeping to express the same sequence of steps.

As for Scanner, the specifics are located [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). It is quite a heavy read, so I will give you a simple example instead:

```
// Make a Scanner to read from the console
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

// Read a line
String s = scan.nextLine();

// Print it
System.out.println(s);
```